# Boxing and unboxing is a myth?

Tags: c#, clr, boxing, unboxing

In C# `Int` type is derived from `ValueType`. `ValueType` is derived from `Object` type. Thus `Int` is an `Object`.

If every value type variable is already an `Object`, then what actually happens during boxing/unboxing?

Comment: There is no type `Int`.  Perhaps you mean `System.Int32` ?

Comment: I suppose your question will be very quickly downvoted to minus infinity, and then closed.

Comment: Read a bit first. This for instance http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Comment: There is a particular memory layout for `Object` instances.  To save space and for compatibility with native code (COM, p/invoke, etc), instances of value types do not conform to that layout.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx does not provide answer for my question.

Comment: @dymanoid this is not a bad question, especially for those who are somewhat new to C#. It does show research effort, as the author has referenced MSDN boxing/unboxing documentation. As a community we need to be more welcoming to new users.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a particular memory layout for `Object` instances.  To save space and for compatibility with native code (COM, p/invoke, etc), instances of value types do not conform to that layout.

"boxing" embeds the value inside an actual "object" instance with the expected layout.  This enables polymorphic use by all the various functions that work on `object` instances and expect that interface.

It's really not correct to say that `Int32` is a subclass of `Object`.  "boxed `Int32`" is, but "unboxed `Int32`" instances do not have any base class subobject at all.  (Among other things, `object` layout includes a pointer to the actual most-derived type of the instance.  The type of value-type objects is determined by their relationship to *something else*, they do not contain the type metadata.  Or a monitor.  Or all the other goodies of `object`.  Boxed versions do.)

Comment: But Int32 IS a subclass of Object. If I derive Cat from Animal and override it's Move method you would not say that Cat is not an instance of Animal just because some methods were overloaded.

Comment: And why instances of value type do not conform memory layout? What is the difference?

Comment: @Ask: I'm not talking about behavior that merely isn't identical, but that the behaviors don't exist. A value type can't have virtual methods because it had no vtable. It can't be used with the lock statement because it contains no monitor.

Comment: And if my Cat is derived from Animal, will it have vtable?

Comment: @Kyle according to the. NET type hierarchy, it is derived from Object. The non obvious thing is that this relationship truly applies to the boxed Int32 instances only.

Comment: @Ask: well if animal is a C# class then yes Cat and animal have vtable. If it is a C# struct then you aren't allowed to inherit from it anyway.

Comment: But ValueType is a class, not a struct. Who is responsible for preventing me to inherit from it? Is it a compiler feature or CLR level restriction?

Comment: Nothing prevents you from "inheriting" from `System.ValueType`.  That's what the C# `struct` keyword does.  In fact, a struct cannot inherit from anything else, not even another struct.  You can't have a class inherit from a struct either, structs are sealed.  Reuse only through composition.  And "inheritance" from ValueType is just metadata, **unboxed instances of value types do not have a base class subobject**.

Comment: Value types are inherited, but don't have subobject? How is it possible?

Comment: @Ask: Because what the C# specification calls "inheritance" is not what you think of as inheritance.  This fake "inheritance" provides an implicit conversion (but it is a boxing conversion, not an upcast) and uses the "base class" field in the metadata.  But this is just an optimization, using metadata memory that would otherwise be wasted, instead of introducing a new bitflag somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Think of `Object` simply as a base class from which ValueType inherits, not a type that represents the *behavior* of the value type. Boxing puts the value type into a reference type wrapper that then makes the value type *behave* like an object.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Both reference and value types are derived from the ultimate base
>   class Object. In cases where it is necessary for a value type to
>   behave like an object, a wrapper that makes the value type look like a
>   reference object is allocated on the heap, and the value type's value
>   is copied into it.